# Change Qt application icons dynamically when language change event

Tags: qt, qt4, translation, qt-creator

I am currently working on a Qt app where the language can be changed dynamically.

To translate the strings, I used a `QTranslator` and overloaded the `changeEvent` method in each of my widgets, and everything is working fine on this side.

It's a different thing with the resources of the projects. Indeed Qt resources can have a `lang` attribute in the resource file (.qrc) of the application, but [it seems that it is only loaded at the application startup, based on the user's locale](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html) which is not what I want. I would like to be able to change these icons dynamically when a LanguageChange event is fired in my code.

I could use rcc files to change the resource file, but it seems that this file will only be loaded at runtime, therefore I won't be able to access the resources in Qt Designer before running the program.

So can I use, let's say, a `resource_en.qrc` file in my application .pro file so I can set my icons with Qt Designer, and then use my `.rcc files` at runtime(resource_fr,etc...) to set the resources dynamically? But how could I unregister a .qrc file from the resources and replace it with an .rcc file (if possible)

Hope I made myself clear enough :D

Thank you :)

Comment: quick search in the documentation [http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application) you can look at "Switching the language", that may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load and unload binary resources using the `QResource::registerResource()` and `QResource::unregisterResource()`

[Dynamic resource loading](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qresource.html#details)

As long as the virtual paths inside each resource file is the same, they should be loaded correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I used this method but I was also asking about how to keep using qrc resources in the Qt project at the same as dynamic ressources at runtime, which doesn't really seem possible. I will accept your answer though !

Answer (score 2):

You can easily load application icon dynamically by using setWindowIcon method. Assuming mainWin is your QMainWindow.

```
if (lang == en)
    mainWin.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/Resources/icon/en-icon.png"));
else if (lang == vn)
    mainWin.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/Resources/icon/vn-icon.png"));
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks but I want to change all the resources used in my project actually not only the app icon. And I don't specify anywhere in the code where my resources are. They are all set using Qt Designer property editor.

Answer (score 1):

Have you can tried to modify your locale using [QLocale](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocale.html)?

```
   QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::Basque, QLocale::Spain));
```